# Reading in Hex values containing letters

Tags: java, hex

I am reading values from the following file

```
02020003
03020004
01000000
0000000A
00000000
```

Using the following code:

```
public static void loader(String file)
{

    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt() ; ++i){
            Memory[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The code correctly reads in the first 3 values in the file, but as soon as it approaches letters, such as that in the 4th line, it stores it as 0 all the time.

Why does this happen ?

Comment: You check for `hasNextInt()`, but use `nextInt(16)`. Do you see anything wrong with that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you, I understand what I did wrong

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Instead of asking a separate question, I had a follow up, when obtaining a hex value i get 30000 when I just want 3. How can I do that ?

Comment: @AlexaVega what do you mean? do you want decimal ?

Comment: @KickButtowski No 3 is a hex value but printing as 30000

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
hasNextInt(int radix)
```

for put radix `16`